# Android 11 update

Tags: android-11, oppo

I use an Oppo A 54 and had received an update prompt that Android 11 update had been downloaded and if I wanted to install it now or later so I clicked on view more details and changed around a few settings. The moment I exited out of the app the Android 11 update had gone and it says my system is completely updated. I have tried restarting the phone but to no avail. I've just bought the phone probably 3 weeks back. Have I lost the update forever? I'm kicking myself right now for not clicking install now right away.

Comment: On most devices the button "check for updates" does not really check every time you press, especially if you had checked some minutes/hours before. Therefore I would assume that the update will appear again in a few days. You can't really block updates on stock Android devices.

Comment: I recommend to stay on android 10 because android 11 is immature